more issues with "Authorize Specific Nodes" Tutorial
I am still having issues with this tutorial. https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/
I have spent today trying to find a solution but have been unable to do so. At step 7 of "Add genesis storage for authorized nodes" it directs to the below code to the GenesisConfig declaration for fn testnet_genesis
 node_authorization: NodeAuthorizationConfig {
   nodes: vec![
     (
       OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2").into_vec().unwrap()),
       endowed_accounts[0].clone()
     ),
     (
       OpaquePeerId(bs58::decode("12D3KooWQYV9dGMFoRzNStwpXztXaBUjtPqi6aU76ZgUriHhKust").into_vec().unwrap()),
       endowed_accounts[1].clone()
     ),
   ],
 },

but in the file I have, it doesn't have that declaration. What I have is
/// Configure initial storage state for FRAME modules.
fn testnet_genesis(
        initial_authorities: Vec<(AuraId, GrandpaId)>,
        root_key: AccountId,
        endowed_accounts: Vec<AccountId>,
        _enable_println: bool,
) -> serde_json::Value {
        serde_json::json!({
                "balances": {
                        // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
                        "balances": endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, 1u64 << 60)).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
                },  
                "aura": {
                        "authorities": initial_authorities.iter().map(|x| (x.0.clone())).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
                },  
                "grandpa": {
                        "authorities": initial_authorities.iter().map(|x| (x.1.clone(), 1)).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
                },  
                "sudo": {
                        // Assign network admin rights.
                        "key": Some(root_key),
                },  
        })  
}

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help. I am trying to learn this by doing it, but it is difficult when the steps don't work. I am trying to get some basic examples up and running so that I can try to illustrate a PoC of the ease of using Polkadot and Substrate, so it is frustrating that I can't get the basic examples working "out of the box" by following the guides. I'm a C++/Linux programmer but not familiar with Rust. The idea was that once I could get them running, I could then modify and add pallets etc. to show what it can do.
When I left it the way it is, it built ok. But when I ran it later, the nodes appeared to be able to see each other, but each said "Peers 0" in the output and I expected to see "Peers 1".

I struggled through these tutorials too! I have taken the time to attempt an update. Maybe you can check out the changes Ive made and see if they help.
updated Authorize Specific Nodes tutorial
